# Why is scrolling is so slow on DotNetBrowser?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

We are looking for chromium browser on .net. We are interested DotNetBrowser  but there is a issue before decide to continue.

Why is scrolling is so slow on DotNetBrowser, chfsharp is much better for scrolling. Is there any  solution for this issue (please check the following video, i compare dotnetbrowser and cefsharp)?

https://youtu.be/ALyRvewbwas

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the large number of mouse events generated in bound Chromium engine.

If you are not interested in handling mouse events for DotNetBrowser control, it is possible to disable them at all or filter out unnecessary events. In this case, this issue will not be reproducible anymore.

Unfortunately such feature is not present in the current version of DotNetBrowser, but the DotNetBrowser team can implement it and provide you with a preview build if it is critical for you.

Comment: Yes, absolutely i don’t want handle mouse events (click, double click, scroll, mouse wheel etc. events) from .net side.  This event handlers  could be optional if possible.

Also  Jquery  or CSS3 effects is slower than  CEF. This issue can be related with unnecessary event listeners.

Comment: My primary expectation from a CEF browser is  silent print, protect local data (indexeddb etc) from end user   and providing standart technologies (File Api, indexeddb etc.)  while work as standart chrome browser.   (As you know  local data can be removed if end-user removes history or data from browser settings)
It will be perfect to see faster DotnetBrowser. I will be waiting for it. 


It is beautiful to see a good support for the product.  Thanks .

Comment: The scrolling smoothness was fixed in DotNetBrowser 1.8.3

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable all events. Smth like this

```
_browser = BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserType.HEAVYWEIGHT); 
_browserView = new WPFBrowserView(_browser);

_browser.DialogHandler = new WPFDefaultDialogHandler(_browserView);
_browser.DownloadHandler = new WPFDefaultDownloadHandler(_browserView);
_browser.ContextMenuHandler = new WPFDefaultContextMenuHandler(_browserView, true);

_browser.Preferences.FireKeyboardEventsEnabled = false;
_browser.Preferences.FireMouseEventsEnabled = false;
_browser.Preferences.FireGestureEventsEnabled = false;
_browser.Preferences.ApplicationCacheEnabled = true;
```